# Javascript fails occasionally (10%ish of the time)

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm having a small issue with my javascript code. I'm trying to use fullCalendar, and 90% of the time it works flawlessly. However, around 10% of the time, it seems to fail to load the fullCalendar function, and I'm not sure why.

I call 3 external scripts above the div that the calendar gets placed into:

```
<script src="../../../../assets/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../assets/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../assets/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

The following is my javascript:

```
//variables to pull the serialized data from c# through to javascript.
var dateStart = '<%=dateStartListToJS%>';
var dateEnd = '<%=dateEndListToJS%>';
var titles = '<%=titlesListToJS%>';
var links = '<%=linksListToJS%>';

//use JSON to parse into arrays.
var dateStartArray = JSON.parse(dateStart);
var dateEndArray = JSON.parse(dateEnd);
var titlesArray = JSON.parse(titles);
var linksArray = JSON.parse(links);

//initiate variable to handle our calendar events.
var JSONEvents = [];

//for testing...
//alert(dateStartArray + dateEndArray + titlesArray + linksArray);

//show the calendar and hide the buttons to switch between the calendar and list.
$("#calendar").show();
$(".viewAsList").hide();
$(".viewAsCalendar").hide();

//while we still have more calendar events to add, run this loop to add courses to the calendar.
//calendar currently only displays the start date of the course.
for (var i = 0; i < dateStartArray.length ; i++) {
    JSONEvents.push(
        {
            "title": titlesArray[i],
            "url": linksArray[i],
            "start": dateStartArray[i],
            "end": dateEndArray[i],
            "allDay": true,
            //"backgroundColor"       :   "#FFF"
        });
}

//function: createCalendar. creates the calendar
function createCalendar() {
    //using fullcalendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //setting up the header of the calendar.
        header: {
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next',
            left: 'title'
            //right: 'month'
        },
        eventColor: '#FCFCFC',
        events: JSONEvents

    });
    $(".viewAsCalendar").show();
    $("#calendar").hide();

    $('.viewAsCalendar').click(function () {
        $(".viewAsCalendar").hide();
        $(".viewAsList").show();
        $("#courseDetailDisplay").hide();
        $("#calendar").show();

    });

    $('.viewAsList').click(function () {
        $(".viewAsCalendar").show();
        $(".viewAsList").hide();
        $("#courseDetailDisplay").show();
        $("#calendar").hide();


    });


}

//if the calendar can't load and an error is thrown, try reloading the calendar
//function loadCalendar() {
//    try {
//        createCalendar();
//    }
//    catch (err) {
//        //alert("test");
//        setTimeout(function () {
//            loadCalendar();
//        }, 4000);

//    }
//}

$(window).load(function () {
    createCalendar();

});
```

When I run the page, it usually works fine, however when it fails, i get an error on the line that contains `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({`, saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Does anyone know why this might be the case? I've tried switching (window).load with (document).ready and (head).ready and neither fixed the issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Based on suggestion I tried the following:

Changed all quotes to double quotes ""
Added a timeout of 150ms
Checked the network tab to see if any files were not loading.

None of the above helped unfortunately, as all 3 files are loading, with a maximum load time of 50ms (usually around 10-15ms).

Any other suggestions folks? I appreicate the help here

Comment: When did your Js is executed?

Comment: At the moment I don't see any problem, no race conditions or something. I guess it doesn't make any difference, but you are mixing `"` and `'` to create Strings. An ugly workaround might be `setTimeout(loadCalendar, 50);`

Comment: Actually, you never call createCalendar(), so the code you show us is not the one you test.

Comment: If it wasn't by accident that it always fails at the same place, then it has to be the `.fullCalendar` because `$('#calendar')` was already used before (but with double quotes `"` there). So I would try my first suggestion. Other workarounds: add the js files to a cache manifest and add the manifest to the site, wait until fullCalendar is defined, try to move the external scripts to the header.

Comment: @romuleald, sorry, my code shows the wrong function name at the end, loadCalendar should actually say createCalendar, I forgot to switch that out when i was cleaning up my code before posting it here. I'll edit it.

Comment: Since it said unrefined, that means the file isn't loaded, use the network of you devtoolbar to see if there's no problem or the fine is empty by whatever reason

Comment: What happens if you change `$(window).load(function () {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`?  Your JS might be executing before the DOM is finished loading.